Azure CLI/ Powershell to get all my Azure subscriptions and export the RoleAssignment
Good day,
I am trying to get all my Azure subscriptions for my tenant and export a list of all the Role Assignments in the Access Control (IAM) panel.
The end goal is to check all the Role Types and check if any Users have access without being in a Group. Once I am done with Subscriptions I also want to check all resource groups.
I will manually populate all CSV's into one, but if there is a way for all data to go into one CSV it would be much easier.
Connect-AzAccount

$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id
    $roleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment
    $filePath = "C:\path\to\your\folder\RoleAssignments_$($subscription.Name).csv"
    $roleAssignments | Export-Csv -Path $filePath -NoTypeInformation
}


you could first get all CSVs and then use import-csv and export-csv
   get-childitem -path "C:\path\to\your\folder\" -filter "*.csv"  |%{
 import-csv -path $_.FullName | export-csv -Path "c:\test\newfile.csv" -Append -Force
 }

or else, you could use directly like below,file name is constant here
$roleAssignments | Export-Csv -Path "c:\test\somestaticfilename.csv" -append -NoTypeInformation


After I connect it gives me a list of subscriptions. Then I get this error when trying the next line.
Select a tenant and subscription:
Connect-AzAccount : Typed subscription is not a number.
At line:1 char:1

Connect-AzAccount

  + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], AzPSException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand



Nevermind, I got it, Had to select a random subscription and then continue
